# Solve an easy problem about Poiseuille equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow

I'm stuck with a very simple problem (at first sight) but I'm unable to solve it. The statement is this:

> A $\rm{50 \ km}$ pipeline transports crude oil (viscosity approx. $\rm{0.8 \ Pa \cdot s}$, density $\rm{0.68 \ g/cm^3}$) to the tanker terminal. The flow rate should be $\rm{500 \ L/s}$ but the flow must be laminar to minimize the required pressure. What is the minimum diameter of the pipeline? What is the pressure loss along the $\rm{50 \ km}$? How can this best be solved?

$$ Q = \frac {\pi R^4(P_1-P_2)}{8\eta L} $$

I know I've to use the Poiseuille equation (given above) but I don't know the pressure and radius, and I don't know what other equation to use.

I'm not asking for the solution, but at least some help because it makes me feel almost angry with myself that don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poiseuille equation will allow you calculate the pressure difference across the pipe once you have found its radius.  However, your job is to calculate the size of the pipe so that the flow is not turbulent. You need to know the Reynolds number for your fluid flow.